# Know when the Access key ID was made inactive

Tags: amazon-iam, identity-management

I've made an Access key ID to "Inactive" state from the IAM and later deleted the Access key ID. Now that I don't have the previous Access key ID details to check when it happened. Could someone help me know from where can I get those details ?

FYI, I've searched in Cloudtrail using the old Access key ID but had no luck.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Instead of searching with the lookup attributes "AWS Access key", I used "Event Name" as lookup attribute.

Got the details from the CloudTrail > Event History > "Event name : UpdateAccessKey"